# what is the meaning of std::swap a variable and a return of function

Tags: c++, std, swap

On project https://github.com/ChisBread/Chis

the code:

```
std::swap(moves,
b.get_turn() == BLK ?
b.get_pruned_moves_black_forvct() : 
b.get_pruned_moves_white_forvct());
```

it is looks like swap a variable and a return of function, and it does not get through the compiler of linux g++,

what is the meaning of swap a variable and a return of function? will a simple assign return of function to the variable do the job
the project is visual c++, and there is Win32 on it somewhere.

Comment: By the way, please always tag questions with the programming language you are asking about (I have added [tag:c++] this time).  Welcome to the site!

Comment: It depends on what the function returns! If it's a temporary, I think it's ill-formed. But if the function returns a reference to an object, it's like swapping with any other object. So it entirely depends on the code in question.